# Is there any way to highlight/spotlight component behind dark color bg of modal?

Tags: react-native

[image: UI Design]

I need to highlight/spotlight component **A** which is a child of component **B** behind dark bg color of the modal

My code is like :

```
<View>
<Modal style = {{backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"}}></Modal>
<B>
<A></A> // I need to highlight/spotlight A component
</B>
</View>
```

I really don't know how to solve this.
I already tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-spotlight but it doesn't work for this case.

Comment: use `zIndex` on <A/>.